# How to enable logging when using Serverless framework

Tags: javascript, webpack, serverless-framework

I currently have a Webpack build which outputs logs as it's running. As soon as I try and run the Webpack build through Serverless (by running `serverless webpack` or `serverless webpack build`) it swallows all the logs and it's difficult to see when Webpack has finished running.

I have checked the documentation and couldn't find anything.

Comment: I recommend you to use https://github.com/FidelLimited/serverless-plugin-optimize instead. I've been using it for a while and it works really well.